# LAN in Ubuntu server is not reconnected after rebooting modem

Tags: network-interface, lan

I have a computer with some home automation stuff connected to the router via LAN, and I only access the computer through SSH, samba shares, and a web interface that it's hosting.

Whenever I power cycle the router, the computer will never reappear on the network, not until I reboot the computer. Since I don't have a keyboard or other peripherals for it, and since I cannot access it through SSH when it's not networked, that means physically pulling the power plug.

Is there a reason why it doesn't automatically reconnect? And is that something I can fix?

Cheers!

---

Computer: Fujitsu Esprimo q520

OS: Ubuntu server 18.04 LTE

Router: Netgear R7000

---

EDIT:

DHCP set up in router to give static IP to the computer.

The computer is connected by cable, not wifi.

Comment: Does the computer have a static IP address or it gets it via DHCP? Can you share some more info on your setup?

Comment: The system will have logs related to the loss of connectivity. You have to study those logs after the forced reboot (hoping this didn't lose them).

Comment: Sure, it gets the IP from the router DHCP. I set i statically in router setup.

Comment: You mean logs on the Ubuntu computer? Is that `/var/logs/syslog` ?

Comment: Connected with cable.